# YouTube Data API returns channel for user without channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've got a YouTube user, which doesn't contain a YouTube channel. But the YouTube data API does return a channel, if I query the youtube.channels.list API method by using the "mine=true" attribute like in following example **(1)**.

Example:

**(1) Returns a channel (mine=true; by using OAuth):**
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails%252Cstatistics&mine=true&_h=5&

This query (1) returns a channel which contains a **channelId**. Now I'm trying to query for the playlists of this channel by using the previously returned **channelId**.

**(2) Returns a 404 "channel not found" error**
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlists.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCIReEy02ibumfYhQP3-0drQ&_h=4&

As described [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1646861?hl=en) it's possible to use a YouTube account without a channel but with limited functionality like using playlists:

> With a Google Account, you can watch and like videos and subscribe to channels. However, without a YouTube channel, you have no public presence on YouTube. Even if you have a Google Account, you need to create a YouTube channel to upload videos, comment, or make playlists. You can use a computer or the YouTube mobile site to create a new channel.

What's the reason query **(1)** is returning a channel even if a YouTube account doesn't contain a channel?

BR
ninsky

Answer (score 0):

**[1] Returns a channel (mine=true; by using OAuth):**

Because of every account on youtube itself a channel. They can do all the things they want like any channel can do e.g. upload videos. Also, we can make multiple channels under the same account.

**[2] Doesn't return a channel (forUsername=UCIReEy02ibumfYhQP3-0drQ; by/without using OAuth):**

Please make sure UCIReEy02ibumfYhQP3-0drQ is a valid username

Comment: Hello Saini, the username in [2] is valid. Regarding your answer on [1] there are also legacy accounts on YouTube so not every account is a channel.

Comment: **[2]**
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&forUsername=tseries&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
See 'tseries' is a valid userName. Why anyone wants UCIReEy02ibumfYhQP3-0drQ to be the username. It is 'userId' i think

Comment: **[1]** What do mean by legacy accounts. Is anything written about it somewhere?

Why I concluded that I have used [Subscription.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) API. They all have a 'channelId'. They can upload videos without adding any other channel. Some of them just made their Google accounts.

Comment: Rahul, I've completely reworked my question due to your answer. I've posted the wrong query in (2). Thanks for pointing me to the right direction but my question is still the same. Regarding legacy accounts on YT I've posted a link in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm building something with the YouTube API. I've found a few oddities so far. The first thing is that a channel can have a title of 'blah blah - Topic' so you probably want to screen those out if you want to retrieve channels with their own content. If I'm right in my thinking, these are just channels with Playlists. Example: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6tQSWkTxbPNaJ_LQ-Ia6jQ/

Also be aware that channels don't have to have a unique title.

Finally there are many channels that return nothing from the API Channels.List method, even though they are channels. I'm still figuring these out. I don't think they are returned from searching through the API, but if you get your Channel IDs from another source then this could be an issue.